# Does the DELL T3400 CN-0TP412 Motherboard support PCI-E 3.0?

Tags: graphics-card, motherboard, pci-express

Just a quick question, I've got a DELL T3400 CN-0TP412 Motherboard, and I was wondering if:

- it is compatible with "PCI-E 3.0" video cards?
- Are there any performance implications (if PCI-E is backwards
  compatible)?

Specifically the 'Sapphire Radeon R9 270X Vapor-X 2GB'.

http://www.pccasegear.com/index.php?main_page=product_info&cPath=193_1560&products_id=25511

How would I determine this myself by looking at the specs?

- 3 x PCI Connectors
- 1 x PCI-E x1 Connector
- 2 x PCI-E x4/x8 Connector

Thanks!

Comment: Based on the fact PCI-E 3.0 is backwards capability it does not really matter.  What is far more likely is your power supply won't be able to provide enough power for a card like want you want to purchase.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We’re talking about this thing, right?
[image: Board]

If so, there’s no problem. Performance might be limited somewhat, but considering the CPUs that fit, that won’t matter anyway.

Comment: Yes it is, and thanks for your response! One last question (if you don't mind), IYO, what video card would you recommend upgrading to for gaming? (from a NVIDIA Quadro FX 1700) -> http://www.techpowerup.com/gpudb/index.php?mfgr%5B%5D=nvidia&released%5B%5D=y11_c&released%5B%5D=y08_11&released%5B%5D=y05_08&interface=PCIe+1.0+x16 ? (or am I flogging a dead donkey).

Comment: Well, I certainly wouldn’t expect any miracles, but your current GPU is kinda very bad. So just about anything will do. Do keep in mind however that your CPU is the next limiting factor. Maybe RAM as well, if it isn’t ≥ 4 GB.

Answer (score 1):

I have this computer and this motherboard and "CharlieRB's" answer (above) is incorrect, with regards to it not having a x16 lane PCi express lot.

Not only does the 0TP412 motherboard have a x16 lane slot for PCi express, IT HAS TWO - and both are PCi express 2 slots.  You can spot them even in the picture above.  On the top left quadrant, that long blue slot is called "SLOT2" and the long black slot is called "Slot4" - both are x16 lane slot PCi express 2 slots.

• 2x PCI Express x16

• 1x PCI Express x8

• 3x PCI

And if you don't have a 500 watt power, then get one.  They're easy to install -you'll need it.

Answer (score 0):

From what I found on the Sapphire site, your motherboard is not compatible with this graphics card because you don't have a x16 slot. There are additional power & connector requirements as well, and we did not outline what you have available for power.

The [system requirements](http://www.sapphiretech.com/presentation/product/product_index.aspx?pid=2036&lid=1#) are as follows (my emphasis added):

- **PCI Express® based PC is required with one X16 lane graphics slot

  available on the motherboard.**
- 4X75 Watt 6-pin PCI Express power connector is required for
  CrossFireX™ system.
- 2X75 Watt 6-pin PCI Express power connector is required.
- Installation software requires CD-ROM drive.
- DVD playback requires DVD drive. Blu-ray™ / HD DVD playback requires
  Blu-ray / HD DVD drive.
- 500 Watt Power Supply is required.
- 600WattPower Supply is recommended for CrossFireX™ System.
- 64-bit operating system highly recommended